# Why is Python's BZ2 Decompressor shrinking the block?

Tags: python, bz2

The BZ2 file I'm using is a partial dump of Wikipedia [[here](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20231020/enwiki-20231020-pages-articles-multistream1.xml-p1p41242.bz2)]

Here's a Python code I wrote to test the length of a 10000-byte block before and after decompression:

```py
import bz2

with open('enwiki-20231020-pages-articles-multistream1.xml-p1p41242.bz2', 'rb') as f:
    block = f.read(10000)
    print(len(block))
    block = bz2.BZ2Decompressor().decompress(block)
    print(len(block))
```

It outputs:

```
10000
2560
```

Indicating that the decompressor is somehow *shrinking* the block? How is this possible? Everywhere I searched, it's telling me this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: What does `d = bz2.BZ2Decompressor(); block = d.decompress(block); print(d.needs_input)` give…?

Comment: The size of each block in bzip2 is between 100kB and 900kB, so your "block" size of less than 10kB is way too small to tell how well bzip2 compresses the block.

Comment: @deceze That prints a 'False'. So does that mean that it knows there's more to decompress?

Comment: @RapidReaders Exactly the point.

Comment: @blhsing How do I get it to read all of the 10000-byte block then? The documentation says that if max_length is -1 (which it is by default), then it should be decompressing the whole block, and setting 'needs_input' to True. (Also, I tried doing the bigger block size you suggested. The issue persists. It still prints 2560 after decompression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a bzip2 file may be a concatenation of multiple compressed streams, and `bz2.BZ2Decompressor` decompresses only the first stream from the input data.

Excerpt from the documentation of [`bz2.BZ2Decompressor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html#bz2.BZ2Decompressor):

> **Note:** This class does not transparently handle inputs containing
> multiple compressed streams, unlike `decompress()` and `BZ2File`. If you
> need to decompress a multi-stream input with BZ2Decompressor, you must
> use a new decompressor for each stream.

In your example, the first stream is 2560 bytes long after decompression, and the second stream begins at what's left of the buffer after the decompression of the first stream, stored in the [`unused_data`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html#bz2.BZ2Decompressor.unused_data) attribute of the decompressor instance, which you can decompress by instantiating a new `bz2.BZ2Decompressor` instance as noted in the documentation.

You can therefore implement code that decompresses an entire bzip2 file in 10000-byte chunks by iteratively reading from either `unused_data` of the current decompressor instance or the next chunk of the file:

```
import bz2

decompressed = []
with open('enwiki-20231020-pages-articles-multistream1.xml-p1p41242.bz2', 'rb') as f:
    decompressor = bz2.BZ2Decompressor()
    while chunk := decompressor.unused_data or f.read(10000):
        if decompressor.eof:
            decompressor = bz2.BZ2Decompressor()
        decompressed.append(decompressor.decompress(chunk))

print(sum(map(len, decompressed)))
```

This outputs the total size of the uncompressed data of the given sample bzip2 file:

```
1018211968
```

And the actual content of the entire decompressed data will be:

```
b''.join(decompressed)
```

Comment: Very interesting. I had no idea files that were concatenations of multiple streams needed to be handled differently, but that makes sense. There appear to be multiple of these "chunks" that have no value in them (after decompression). Any clue why?